# Save to clipboard with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to save to clipboard some text added dynamicaly in multiple `div`.

**GOAL :** I have multiple div (Dynamicaly added. Can be 2 or 9999) and want a button (save to clipboard) for each `textarea`.

```js
var copyTextareaBtn = document.querySelector('.js-textareacopybtn');

copyTextareaBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var copyTextarea = document.querySelector('.js-copytextarea');
  copyTextarea.select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }
});
```

```html
<div1>
  <textarea class="js-copytextarea" style="width:100%;" rows="5">This is the text that will be selected. Note that you can hide this and implement a secret copy feature.</textarea>
  <button class="js-textareacopybtn">Copy Textarea text</button>
</div1>

<div2>
  <textarea class="js-copytextarea2" style="width:100%;" rows="5">This is the text that will be selected. Note that you can hide this and implement a secret copy feature.</textarea>
  <button class="js-textareacopybtn2">Copy Textarea text</button>
</div2>

<div3>
  <textarea class="js-copytextarea3" style="width:100%;" rows="5">This is the text that will be selected. Note that you can hide this and implement a secret copy feature.</textarea>
  <button class="js-textareacopybtn3">Copy Textarea text</button>
</div3>
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery really ?

Comment: That's not a problem, that's your goal. What is the problem you're having with this code specifically? When you try it what happens?

Comment: Well, it saves the first textarea, not the second if I click on the second button. I know it's a normal behavior, Just want some help to get the right way

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Despite the question not including jQuery, if OP is open to a jQuery solution, does it not make sense to include the tag?

Comment: That why I have asked..

Comment: So yes, I may use Jquery if needed

Comment: @user1708580 Your first selector is `.js-textareacopybtn` - I don't see any elements that have this class, therefore it selects nothing. You then try to attach an event listener to it - but again, it's attaching to nothing. You can see in the snippet console that you get a `Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null` error because of this.

Comment: With your edit, your first textbox now works as the element is found. You don't need multiple classes - rather, it would be much easier if you just had *one* on each element. Then each button could simply perform the logic "Copy the previous text area's content".

Comment: @Santi this is exactly what I want, but how to tell "select the textarea just before" ?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Posted an answer that does just that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using the jQuery library you could attach the click event using the event delegation **[`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** to the common classes, so i'll affect the dynamically added ones, like :

```
$('body').on('click', '[class^="js-textareacopybtn"]', function(){
  $(this).prev('textarea').select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }
})
```

**NOTE :** The following line will retrieve the previous `textarea` related to the clicked `button` then select it :

```
$(this).prev('textarea').select();
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('body').on('click', '[class^="js-textareacopybtn"]', function(){
  $(this).prev('textarea').select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }
})
```

```css
This is the text that will be selected. Note that you can hide this and implement a secret copy feature 1.This is the text that will be selected. Note that you can hide this and implement a secret copy feature 2.This is the text that will be selected. Note that you can hide this and implement a secret copy feature 3.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div1>
  <textarea class="js-copytextarea1" style="width:100%;" rows="5">This is the text that will be selected. Note that you can hide this and implement a secret copy feature 1.</textarea>
  <button class="js-textareacopybtn1">Copy Textarea text 1</button>
</div1>

<div2>
  <textarea class="js-copytextarea2" style="width:100%;" rows="5">This is the text that will be selected. Note that you can hide this and implement a secret copy feature 2.</textarea>
  <button class="js-textareacopybtn2">Copy Textarea text 2</button>
</div2>

<div3>
  <textarea class="js-copytextarea3" style="width:100%;" rows="5">This is the text that will be selected. Note that you can hide this and implement a secret copy feature 3.</textarea>
  <button class="js-textareacopybtn3">Copy Textarea text 3</button>
</div3>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Not sure to understand it's going to select the good textarea

Comment: I'm not the one who posted this answer, but it's entirely correct. `$(this)` refers to the button that was clicked, therefore `$(this).prev('textarea')` will always refer to the `textarea` just before the clicked button.

Comment: That's perfect !

Comment: I tried adding success popup alert("success"); instead of console message but the popup is displayed for each textarea

Comment: On success, instead of console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);

Comment: Then just change _console.log_ by _alert_ .. is that doesn't gives you the desired behavious ?!

Comment: yes sorry, I've just noticed that my script was duplicated for each "textarea". Thank you very much !